# Prevent jQuery Mobile from Adding Custom Classes to Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Using jQuery Mobile, how can I prevent it from adding its own elements and classes? For example, my original HTML is:

```
<div id="main-table">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <form method="get">
                <input name="SearchOrders" class="myInput" type="text" value="" />
                <input name="SendSearch" class="redButton searchButton" type="submit" value="" />
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But jQuery Mobile adds some divs and classes:

```
<div id="main-table">
    <ul class="my-account myTitle">
        <li>
            <form method="get">
                <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
                    <input name="SearchOrders" class="myInput" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
                    <input name="SendSearch" class="redButton searchButton" type="submit" value="">
                </div>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I use  data-role="none" on each element, jQuery Mobile won't modify my markup but I'm looking for a solution where I don't need to modify my HTML.

I've tried:

```
$(document).on('mobileinit',function(){
    $.mobile.keepNative = 'input';
});
```

But that doesn't work.

I've also tried:

```
data-enhance="false"
```

On a parent element but that doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQueryMobile documentation: [Configuring Defaults](http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/):

> The mobileinit event
>
> When jQuery Mobile starts, it triggers a mobileinit event on the
>   document object. To override default settings, bind to mobileinit.

The keypoint here is: the configuration override shall be available as jQuery Mobile starts, so you should put your configuration script in the head before loading the jQuery Mobile file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
      $.mobile.keepNative = "input";
    });
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-1">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Native Inputs</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div id="main-table">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <form method="get">
              <input name="SearchOrders" class="myInput" type="text" value="" />
              <input name="SendSearch" class="redButton searchButton" type="submit" value="" />
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```